# How do Firefox and Chrome start up out of focus? How can I prevent it?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, private-browsing

I have first noticed with Google Chrome that when I open an incognito tab from the taskbar or start menu, the newly opened window start out of focus. It is really annoying for me because I have to do one extra click (to bring the browser window in focus) every time I open a new browser window.

I am used to `right click -> New private window -> start typing the address or search term`.
But now it has to be `right click -> New private window -> click to bring in focus -> start typing`. See the attached image for a demo.

With the latest firefox update (89.0), it has also started showing the same behavior.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Is there any way I can go back to the `right click -> New private window -> start typing`?

[image]

Comment: no one? I am really frustrated to go against my years long habit. Please help to avoid it or have some closure.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue. I opened the on screen keyboard and tested both Google Chrome and Firefox. Both start focused and typing instantly appears in the address bars. This works for both regular and private browsing windows.

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure you are checking on Win 10? I have the same problem on all the PCs and laptops I use from time to time. Probably 4 of them, all from different backgrounds. By the way, the onscreen keyboard was just to show you that the typing doesn't work. The problem is the same with the regular keyboard as well.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise(20H2). The physical keyboard is also the same and instantly types in the address bar for Chrome(91.0.4472.101)  and Firefox(89.0) with normal and private windows. Even on a virtual machine it also works as expected(same version of Win 10 Enterprise). At the moment I don't have any other version of Win 10 such as Home or Pro. Out of curiosity I did test on Windows Server 2019 Standard(1809) and that also worked properly. You've done a great job with the animated example here, but sadly, I am not sure where to look without being able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BoogaRoo. I love your dedication.

Comment: Any Firefox experts here?